# mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id-'$id'"); fails

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete a row from my mySQL database via PHP and it isn't working.  I have tried the following:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id='$id'");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM 'table' WHERE id='$id'");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id=`$id`");
```

$id is the unique identifier and I've echoed it to make sure it's coming across.  Using "or die" results in death.  The row simply won't go away.

Any other syntax I should try?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @Neil McGuigan: irrelevant until you know for sure how it is processed

Comment: Did you check the error message when it resulted in death?

Comment: I did not get an error message.  I'm unfamiliar with most error checking methods.  How do I get the error to print to screen?

Comment: `die(mysql_error())` will print the error and then kill the script

Comment: I get:
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
But I know I'm connecting.  I'm even running a query to check deletion privileges before running the delete query.

...

OH MY GOD I closed the connection after the first query!

Comment: Fixed.  Removing the extra mysql_close();  At least I learned how to error check correctly and to be careful when I cut and paste my code.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you were trying to try every possible combination, but it helps to know what the specific punctuations actually mean in the MySQL syntax.

```
`structure`
```

Grave accents are used only around structures like column names, etc.

```
'value'
```

Apostrophes are used for the values, as in `id='$id'`.

---

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id='$id'");
```

This is valid syntax. You can also put grave accents around `table`.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM 'table' WHERE id='$id'");
```

This is invalid syntax. `'table'` is invalid, since it's a column not a value.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id=`$id`");
```

This is invalid syntax. You put grave accents around the value, when it should have been apostrophes.

---

Hopefully those explanations helps you figure out your issues.

Comment: That is helpful, in general, but my problem persists.  Thanks for the calcification, though.

Answer (score 2):

The error checking helped me discover that I had a `mysql_close();` before my second `mysql_query`.  My syntax was correct, I just didn't check the remainder of the code carefully enough.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `id` integer? Try

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id=$id");
```

Comment: @WebMeister could you provide some error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id=".$id);
```

I ask because you may be quoting a number (your id) - and you don't need (or want) to do that.

Let me know if this works - I'm no expert but it's my first glimpse at it.

Comment: I'm afraid that did not work.