# Delete a entry from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have made an sql database with some records, and I have a table to show that records. My question is how to delete this record. I have made the code but is wrong. Any suggestions?

The Table:

```
<?php                                               
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,onoma_pelati,tilefono,fax,email FROM visitors");
if (!$result) {
    die("Problem...");
}

$fields_num=mysql_num_fields($result);                                  
$counter = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $counter . "</td>";
    foreach($row as $cell)
    {
        echo "<th>$cell</th>";
    }
    echo '<td class="column"> 
       <a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><img src="images/icons/color/cross.png" /></a> </td></tr>';                                       
    $counter++;
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

And the delete file:

```
<?php
include('db_connection.php');

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM visitors WHERE id=$id")
    or die(mysql_error());

    header("Location: showplio.php");
}
else
{
    header("Location: addplio.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: just want to ask that are you getting something in -$id- at delete file. plz check.

Comment: "the code but is wrong" - what is happening exactly? Any error messages?

Comment: the error is :  Illegal string offset 'id' in on line : Illegal string offset 'id' in on line : Illegal string offset 'id' in on line

Comment: Try commenting out the sql_query and use print_r for $id and tell me what you get..

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919217/mysql-querydelete-from-table-where-id-id-fails?rq=1), seems to be similare.

Comment: I'm getting only one id..id=2.

Comment: Can you show us var_dump($_GET) ? The warning message sounds like the id get parameter is not defined

Comment: which page is showing the error?

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code suffers from an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can take advantage of [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).  You should also *never* be taking data-manipulating action based off of a GET request.  Make data changes (adds, changes, deletes) *only* as the result of a POST.  See also [cross-site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_fetch_row` function you are using returns the rows as an array with numeric indices, so instead of `$row['id']` you have to use `$row[0]`.

You can alternatively use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). This function returns the rows as an array with string indices, so `$row['id']` would work.

It would be even better to [use a different MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) because the `mysql_`-functions are not recommended for new development.

Comment: Thank all for your answers. I use this : mysql_fetch_assoc ,and works perfectly. Thank you again.